# Job Scheduler Not starting instantly on Android Lollipop(5.1.1)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-jobscheduler

I have been working with Job Scheduler API. For Marshmallow it works perfectly.
But for Lollipop Device(5.1.1) it does not starts instantly (takes random number of minutes). What i Mean to say is the onStartJob() method takes some time to invoke.

Following is the code snippet with Which i am scheduling my Job.

```
private void scheduleJob() {
    ComponentName serviceName = new ComponentName(this, SampleJobService.class);
    JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1000, serviceName)
        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_NONE)
        .setRequiresCharging(false)
        .setPeriodic(60 * 1000)
        .build();

    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) this.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    int result = scheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
    if (result == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        Log.e("khushank", "Job scheduled successfully!");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Job scheduled successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Log.e("khushank", "not able to start result: " + result);
    }
}
```

And following is my Simple Job Service which Just write the logs

```
public class SampleJobService extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

        Log.e("khushank","job started with id = "+params.getJobId());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.e("khushank","job Stopped with id = "+params.getJobId());
        return false;
    }
}
```

And when i run this sample Application the logs are printed like  this :

```
12-16 16:28:17.040 27119-27119/com.example.inkkashy02.myapplication E/khushank: Job scheduled successfully!
12-16 16:29:17.032 27119-27119/com.example.inkkashy02.myapplication E/khushank: job started with id = 1000
```

Not able to debug why it takes almost a minute to call onStartJob() in Lollipop.
For Marshmallow it gets invoked as soon as job is scheduled.
Please tell the root cause of this problem.

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing in the `JobScheduler` API and docs that say that the first job will happen immediately. What makes you think that there is a problem?

Comment: @CommonsWare Since  i have kept the setRequiredNetworkType to be NETWORK_TYPE_NONE it should start the Job as soon as i schedule it. In my case the Job Scheduler returns RESULT_SUCCESS but onStatJob() is not called immediately,it takes random number of minutes.

Comment: @CommonsWare Since  i have kept the setRequiredNetworkType to be NETWORK_TYPE_NONE it should start the Job as soon as i schedule it. In my case the Job Scheduler returns RESULT_SUCCESS but onStatJob() is not called immediately,it takes random number of minutes.
So when according to you the job should start when Job Scheduler returns RESULT_SUCCESS and why is it that the same Job Scheduler runs immediately in Marshmallow.

Comment: "Since i have kept the setRequiredNetworkType to be NETWORK_TYPE_NONE it should start the Job as soon as i schedule it" -- please provide a link to the documentation that describes this behavior, as I do not see this documented anywhere. "why is it that the same Job Scheduler runs immediately in Marshmallow" -- AFAIK, it is not documented exactly when it will begin. For `setPeriodic()`, I would expect it to first occur somewhere within that period. However, your one-minute period may be too low.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but I found exactly the same issue on my Oppo F1F and Android 5.1.1 - OK on later phones I tested on.  I tried network none as well, but even with the following which should force the immediacy it was not:

```
    JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(++jobId, componentName)
            .setMinimumLatency(1)
            .setOverrideDeadline(1)
            .build();
```

I read elsewhere minimum latency of 0 would cause this issue, hence set to 1; set override deadline of 1 should be maximum timeout if other constraints have not been met.  To be fair I never tried 2.  My solution was to just only use jobs from Android 8; I figured bugs ironed out by then!  Did you come to any resolution?

Comment: I switched to using jobs on just Android 8; however have since dropped using them for my application on this as well.  The reason being that despite the application being whitelisted from doze (I need to wake up, I am a GPS tracker logging every few seconds) the background jobs were still subject to doze on some phones ... but not others.  I think Android 9 has some new API to resolve this use case.